# MySQL - Fetch data 30 days before its expiration date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch data whose expiration date is within 30 days of today.
I've tried using `BETWEEN` clause but still not working.

table name **registration**:

```
id               exp_date

12                05-20-2018
19                05-19-2018
34                05-22-2018
```

let say the date today is `04-28-2018`. Which I stored in a variable `$date_today`

```
$date_today = '04-28-2018';
$query = "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE expiration_date BETWEEN('$date_today', DATE_SUB(expiration_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)";
        $test =  mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc1( $test);
```

and this the error that I'm getting:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

Comment: Could you try using `BETWEEN ... AND ...` but swap the dates around, so the earlier date is on the left.  Not sure if the order of the dates matters though.

Comment: Store dates as dates

Comment: Which rows are you trying to match? Which ones shouldn't be returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BETWEEN` is not a function, it's an operator. The syntax is:

```
BETWEEN low_value AND high_value
```

You should also stop using variable substitution and use prepared statements with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

To get everything that's expiring within the next 30 days, you want:

```
WHERE exp_date BETWEEN CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Notice that this uses `DATE_ADD()`, not `DATE_SUB()`, since you want expiration dates in the future, not the past.

Comment: thanks for that, error was removed but still no data

Comment: @Barmar I need to get the data or the `id` 30 days before it's expiration date. Meaning today `april 28, 2018` and the expiration is `may 10, 2018`  .The query should get the id which expiration date is `may 10, 2018`

Comment: You mean everything that is expiring between today and May 28?

Comment: @Barmar working fine! thanks, will review the functions given here

Answer (score 0):

For sql server,to check items which will expire within a period of 1-7days

```
select sdate, edate, DATEDIFF(MONTH,GETDATE(),edate) as MONTHS from Stockin 
where DATEDIFF(MONTH,GETDATE(),edate) between 1 and 7
order by edate desc
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUWJV.png)

Answer (score -1):

I hope it will work for you.

```
DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE(),expiration_date) >= 30
```

Comment: It should be `<=`. But you also have to check that it's `>= 0`, he doesn't want expiration dates in the past.

Comment: if you look at question he is asking 30 days before expiry

Comment: None of the dates in his sample data will be matched by your answer.

Comment: Your code matches *more* than 30 days before expiry.

Comment: he can change it to his requirement from >=30 to =30.

Comment: Since he's using `BETWEEN`, I think he means "within 30 days", which is `<=`.

Comment: "Fetch data 30 days before its expiration date" this is what he is asking, not within 30 days.

Comment: i don't think so if you give me -1 for the answer. Because it is very clear from his question that he wants rows  30 days before its expiration date.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted, maybe it's just because the answer posts code without any explanation of the original problem or how this solves it. Code without explanation is a poor answer.

Comment: He's clarified the question, he means expiring sometime in the next 30 days.